# Referencing css and js files in bootstrap

Tags: spring-boot

[image]

I am trying to reference to my css files as shown in the image. Since my index.html is in the templates folder, i have to go back 1 level up(../), and then go into static/css/{the file that i want}. However, this fails to render my css and js files. What am i doing wrong here? I am using thymelead templating engine for this spring boot application. Please help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring-Boot and Thymeleaf works well together. By default Spring-Boot look up for static resources in those folders.

- `/META-INF/resources`
- `/resources/`
- `/static/`
- `/public/`

So you dont need to go back to any upper level. Your reference should normally work like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. May I ask whats the use of adding in th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"? Can i just add href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" and omit the other and vice versa? Thanks very much

Comment: @Desmond your welcome. Just look up [the docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) for th:href. Its the springStandard way.